# Relationships beetween Complied/Interpreted/Scripting and other programming language classifications?

Tags: programming-languages

I got lost in the classifications of programming languages. What is the relationships between "Compiled/Interpreted/Scripting" and "OOP/Procedural/Functional", and possibly many "terms" for classifying languages?

I do not even know how to ask this properly. Looked for programming language hierarchy but every diagram is always missing some terms above.

Answer (score 0):

There is not really a relationship between them, as they are different classification systems.

**OOP/Procedural/Functional** describe the syntax and grammar of a programming language.
It describes what a language looks like to the software programmer.

**Compiled/Interpreted/Scripting** describes how the language is processed, and what is necessary for a program to run.
Compiled languages are transformed into machine code before execution, interpreted and scripting languages are transformed into machine code during execution.

**Examples** of languages and their classification in either system:

- Java is a OOP Compiled language.
- Kotlin is a functional compiled language.
- Python is a procedural interpreted language.
- Javascript is a functional scripting language